# Is there a site for discussing history of art?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange community for discussing about the history of art?

I am interested in this subject, the evolution of art (painting), the evolution of art movements in history, and appreciation of paintings by famous artists.

Comment: Note that none of the Stack Exchange communities actually do *discussions*. They all require *specific questions* that can be reasonably answered.

Answer (score 13):

There's a [history site](https://history.stackexchange.com) that has an [art](/questions/tagged/art) tag. That [tag's description](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/art) is:

> Questions related to history of art or artists

Which sounds about right. You could look through the questions against that tag and see how they were received. You can find further information about the site in general in its [help centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Would it be on topic to ask questions there about "what is this historic artistic style"